# Django: how can I check whether any one of forms, stackedInlineforms has changed in admin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

**admin.py**

```
class ItemInline(AdminImageMixin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 0
    fields = (
        'variation',
        'ordered_original_unit_price',
        'width',
        'height',
        'quantity',
        'ordered_sale_percent',
        'total_price',
        'image1',
        'image2',
    )
    form = ItemImageAdminForm


class PaymentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Payment
    extra = 0
    fields = (
        'pay_method',
        'bank',
        'account_owner',
        'due_date',
        'cash_receipt',
        'cash_receipt_for',
        'cash_receipt_method',
        'cash_receipt_of'
    )
    form = PaymentAdminForm


class WorkScheduleInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = WorkSchedule
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1
    fields = (
        'work_date',
        'work_time',
    )
    form = WorkScheduleAdminForm


class OrderAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
            'js/order_admin.js',
        )
    inlines = [WorkScheduleInline, PaymentInline, ItemInline, ]
    form = OrderAdminForm
```

As you can see above, `OrderAdmin` has three `inlineAdmin`s which has its own custom `form`.

What I want to do is :

If any of field change detected among the forms, send message to client.

What I've tried is to insert `has_changed()` method inside of each `form`'s `is_valid()` method and send message according to its result.

It might seem look good, but problem is that if there were changes in field of each 4 forms, then it sends four messages instead of only one message.

How can I deal with it so that I do only one task(send message) if changes detected?

**Edit**

Each `Form` has this code:

```
def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.has_changed():
        send_message();
    return super().is_valid(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: **it sends four messages instead of only one message** Where is that code..?? has_change() method..??

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I edited it

Comment: You know how to use a global variable in python ..?? Then I have a suggestion/solution for you.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I think that global variable very bad idea... Sort of race condition could happen